# Just set up SSIS and MS 2012, getting permissions error and don't know where to proceed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, connection

I just started using SSIS and am trying to upload an Excel file.  When I get to the Excel Connection Manager and use the variable pointing to the file path of it's location, I get the following error:

"An OLE DB record is available.  Source:  "Microsoft JET Database Engine" HRresult: 0x80004005 Description:  "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file".  IT is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data."

The SQL Server and SSIS software are brand new.  The destination table is already set up.  What could I try to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a lock on the file (on the server, right-click my computer, manager, system tools, shared folders, open files).

OR look for Excel Version in Excel connection manager, choose MS excel 97-2003. I assume you are using new version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the spreadsheet open in Excel, it will put a lock on the file and prevent it from being opened by SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes if excel didn't close properly it might leave an instance in memory locking your file. You may need to check it with Task Manager and kill the excel instances manually.

Answer (score -1):

Close out of Server Manager or Visual Studio. It will release the file.